# The MBean class could not be loaded by the default loader repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, jmx, classnotfoundexception

The title says everything. I'm running a simple example of how to use JMX to remotely manage objects. It works fine with command lines but within Eclipse I get a `javax.management.ReflectionException` saying

> The MBean class could not be loaded by the default loader repository
>   The class implementing the "somethingMBean" is not found "ClassNotFoundException".

Any idea please about how to solve that problem?

Regards

Jean

Answer (score 2):

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs because the particular class is not in the classpath. Check the particular library is in the classpath.